# Type definition that exports both the type and class definition on a namespace

Tags: typescript, type-definition

I'm working on a type definition for a 3rd party JS library ([Handsontable](https://handsontable.com/)) that exports a class and namespace of top-level APIs, conceptually like this:

```
import Car from "car-lib";
new Car(); // Create instances
Car.garage.get("mustang"); // Static top-level APIs.
```

This can be modeled by exporting a `class` with `static` members for namespaces.

However, some of the class static namespaces export class definitions, and I'm having a hard time correctly exposing both the type and the class definition for usage.

Example:

```
declare namespace Car {
  namespace parts {
    class Engine { vroom(); }
  }
  interface Parts {
    EnginePart: typeof parts.Engine; // Error: Property 'Engine' does not exist on type 'Parts'.
  }
}
declare class Car {
  static parts: Car.Parts;
}

export default Car;

// This works as desired
let engine: Car.parts.Engine;
engine.vroom();

// This should work but I get:
// Error: Type 'Engine' is not a constructor function type.
class V8 extends Car.parts.EnginePart { }

// This does not work, as desired
class V6 extends Car.parts.Engine { } // Error: Property 'Engine' does not exist on type 'Parts'.
```

Try it in [the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20namespace%20Car%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20namespace%20parts%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20Engine%20%7B%20vroom()%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20interface%20Parts%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20EnginePart%3A%20typeof%20parts.Engine%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Property%20'Engine'%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'Parts'.%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Adeclare%20class%20Car%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20parts%3A%20Car.Parts%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20default%20Car%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20works%20as%20desired%0D%0Alet%20engine%3A%20Car.parts.Engine%3B%0D%0Aengine.vroom()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20should%20work%20but%20I%20get%3A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Type%20'Engine'%20is%20not%20a%20constructor%20function%20type.%0D%0Aclass%20V8%20extends%20Car.parts.EnginePart%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20does%20not%20work%2C%20as%20desired%0D%0Aclass%20V6%20extends%20Car.parts.Engine%20%7B%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Property%20'Engine'%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'Parts'.).

My current workaround is to give the [internal namespace a different name](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/blob/c2ba2dc02e3eb883a58f976ef5944fa629dc981d/handsontable.d.ts#L172), like `_parts`, but this leads to some issues:

```
declare namespace Car {
  namespace _parts {
    class Engine { vroom(); }
  }
  interface Parts {
    EnginePart: typeof _parts.Engine;
  }
}
declare class Car {
  static parts: Car.Parts;
}

export default Car;

// This requires referencing the "_parts" for type annotation, yuck
let engine: Car._parts.Engine;
engine.vroom();

// This works as desired
class V8 extends Car.parts.EnginePart { }

// Problem: this should not be allowed (and will be a runtime error) but it is allowed
class V6 extends Car._parts.Engine { }
```

Try it in [the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20namespace%20Car%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20namespace%20_parts%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20Engine%20%7B%20vroom()%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20interface%20Parts%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20EnginePart%3A%20typeof%20_parts.Engine%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Adeclare%20class%20Car%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20parts%3A%20Car.Parts%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20default%20Car%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20requires%20referencing%20the%20%22_parts%22%20for%20type%2C%20yuck%0D%0Alet%20engine%3A%20Car._parts.Engine%3B%0D%0Aengine.vroom()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20works%20as%20desired%0D%0Aclass%20V8%20extends%20Car.parts.EnginePart%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Problem%3A%20this%20should%20not%20be%20allowed%20(and%20will%20be%20a%20runtime%20error)%20but%20it%20is%20allowed%0D%0Aclass%20V6%20extends%20Car._parts.Engine%20%7B%20%7D).

What's the right way to do this, so that the first example's usages (everything after `export default Car`) behave as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty you have is caused by trying to solve two problems at the same time: type declaration and type publication (lack of a better term).

The solution is to first declare the types, and then wire them up to match the shape exposed (publicize) by the JavaScript library.

```
declare namespace CarParts {
  class CarEngine { vroom(); }
}

interface CarParts {
  EnginePart: typeof CarParts.CarEngine;
}

declare namespace Car {
  namespace parts {
    type Engine = CarParts.CarEngine
  }
}
declare class Car {
  static parts: CarParts;
}

export default Car;

let engine: Car.parts.Engine;
engine.vroom();

// This works as desired
class V8 extends Car.parts.EnginePart { }

// This is shown as error as expected
class V6 extends Car.parts.Engine { }
```

Here is the [playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20namespace%20CarParts%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20class%20CarEngine%20%7B%20vroom()%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20CarParts%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20EnginePart%3A%20typeof%20CarParts.CarEngine%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20namespace%20Car%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20namespace%20parts%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%20Engine%20%3D%20CarParts.CarEngine%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Adeclare%20class%20Car%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20parts%3A%20CarParts%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20default%20Car%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20engine%3A%20Car.parts.Engine%3B%0D%0Aengine.vroom()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20works%20as%20desired%0D%0Aclass%20V8%20extends%20Car.parts.EnginePart%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20is%20shown%20as%20error%20as%20expected%0D%0Aclass%20V6%20extends%20Car.parts.Engine%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A)